# Rendering open sans google web fonts with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-webfonts

I'm trying to use google web fonts open sans with bootstrap.

I'm loading the fonts with:

I have a site-specific.css that loads after bootstrap. I've tried:

```
.body { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
```

and also:

```
.bootstrap-container *,    
.bootstrap-container body, 
.bootstrap-container td, 
.bootstrap-container tr, 
.bootstrap-container div, 
.bootstrap-container p, 
.bootstrap-container form, 
.bootstrap-container input, 
.bootstrap-container select, 
.bootstrap-container textarea, 
.bootstrap-container font {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

But it seems that no matter what class selector I use, the fonts don't render and the bootstrap fonts are inherited instead. I'm not sure how to debug this.

Comment: Why don't you just customize Bootstrap?

Answer (score 9):

Provided you haven't altered the core files of Bootstrap, I would make this easier on yourself and use their "customise" feature. Re-download it after placing your font names in and replace your existing bootstrap files with the new ones.

**You can customise it here:**

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Doing this will at least ensure that you don't miss something...and please, avoid using `!important` as suggested above (unless you *really* need to).
Hope that helps?

Comment: just insert 'Open Sans' in the box @sansFontFamily on the customize page before downloading it, and don't forget to include the link from google webfonts api in the head of your document

Comment: I'm using bootstrap from the bootstrap CDN. I'll try this method though. I just don't understand why the overriding inherited font styles seems so difficult.

Comment: Did this work for you? Have you considered accepting an answer as correct? This will help others in future with similar problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS `!important`

```
.bootstrap-container *,    
.bootstrap-container body, 
.bootstrap-container td, 
.bootstrap-container tr, 
.bootstrap-container div, 
.bootstrap-container p, 
.bootstrap-container form, 
.bootstrap-container input, 
.bootstrap-container select, 
.bootstrap-container textarea, 
.bootstrap-container font {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; <-------- Here
}
```

Comment: !important didn't have any effect on the rendered output.